# Who is this character laying on Qyburn's table?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the 5th season, we see this scene:

> https://vine.co/v/eW9bUtEBJO6

As displayed in the picture:

[image]

But, it appears to me that this has not yet been re-visited and I'm still clueless as to who he is, and what he actually had tied onto the bed.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: I believe it is because you used a vine link and did not describe textually what exactly were you talking about. Which is why I added a screenshot of the scene. And also because it suggests that you were not following the show after this episode or in this episode. (Low research).

Comment: Downvotes, because there is clearly no research. He comes back in that same season...

Answer (score 4):

That person is Ser [Gregor Clegane](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gregor_Clegane), aka The Mountain (or as in the books, [Ser Robert Strong](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_Strong)). After his duel with Prince Oberyn Martell, Gregor was struck with a poisoned spear which was slowly killing him. Qyburn starts using certain magical and medical arts on him, converting him into this:

[image]

According to [Show Wikia about the event](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gregor_Clegane):

> A moribund Gregor Clegane is being experimented on by Qyburn at his
>   laboratory in the dungeons below the Red Keep. Queen Cersei visits
>   Qyburn and asks him about the state of his work, while glancing at
>   Gregor's covered body, and Qyburn assures her it is going very well,
>   though there is still a way to go. Then, **Gregor suddenly spasms, and
>   Qyburn gently shushes him and tells him to go easy**.

It is not clear exactly what Qyburn did to Gregor to make him come back from the dead but when Jaime asked what Qyburn did in season 6, Qyburn only replied:

> A number of things

Since he is already a part of Season 5 & 6, I'd say that his story line has been revisited over and over again. It is not like they left his story dangling there like Gendry's.

Comment: What episode(s) did this happen in? I haven't seen any of this :(!

Comment: You might wanna watch 2nd, 3rd, 8th & 10th episode of season 5 to cover the whole transformation

Comment: Haha, I love how you included that quote from Qyburn. He's kind of a smartass in the show.